# Half way between absolute and relative

Tags: css

I am trying to get some menus to look good, but I seem to have two options that do half of what I want.  What can I do that will give me both of the behaviors I want?

The problem is with the offset in my menu.  When I set the submenu to relative.  Everything expands as it shouldn't.  When a submenu is moused over it expands in place instead of off to the right as I would like it to.  The jsfiddle below shows this behavior:

http://jsfiddle.net/7a4dzxt2/

When I use absolute, all the sub menus are stuck to the left.  They exapnd exactly as I would like, but each menu is all the way on the left of the screen and not directly below the main menu item.  The jsfiddle below shows this:

http://jsfiddle.net/w8ztr9eb/

The code that is being changed is:

```
#navbar ul li ul {
     display:none;
     position:absolute;
     left: 30px;
     background-color:transparent;
     padding:10px;
     opacity:0.95;
}
```

To:

```
#navbar ul li ul {
         display:none;
         position:relative;
         left: 30px;
         background-color:transparent;
         padding:10px;
         opacity:0.95;
    }
```

How can I keep the menus from expanding like in the second jsfiddle, but keep the menu from being stuck to the left side of the page?

Comment: Would you explain it a little more..

Comment: Here are some cool ideas that you can follow and think about: http://wtfhtmlcss.com/#floats-block-level e.g. you don't need display:block if you are using float

Comment: @MihirUjjainwal I added some detail.  I hope that helps.  It is a little difficult to explain without visuals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the containing `li` elements to `position: relative` then your absolutely positioned `ul` elements will be positioned in relation to their parent:

```
#navbar ul li {
    /* ... */

    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w8ztr9eb/3/

Comment: Crap beat me to it... Nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's a start. When you use `absolute`, it positions based on the nearest positioned parent. So, try:

```
#navbar ul li {
    position: relative;
}

#navbar ul li ul {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    padding:1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w8ztr9eb/2/